# Hex to string conversion

Tags: c++, string

assuming i have a string containing hexadecimal digits where every 2 hex digits represents a character in the ASCII set and i need to convert the string containing hex digits back to its character equivalent

i found what i was looking for in this code:-

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string hex_to_string(const std::string& input)
{
  static const char* const lut = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  size_t len = input.length();
  if (len & 1) throw std::invalid_argument("odd length");

  std::string output;
  output.reserve(len / 2);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
  {
    char a = input[i];
    const char* p = std::lower_bound(lut, lut + 16, a);
    if (*p != a) throw std::invalid_argument("not a hex digit");

    char b = input[i + 1];
    const char* q = std::lower_bound(lut, lut + 16, b);
    if (*q != b) throw std::invalid_argument("not a hex digit");

    output.push_back(((p - lut) << 4) | (q - lut));
  }
  return output;
}
```

i am rather new to C++ and i could understand till the part output.push_back(((p - lut) << 4) | (q - lut));
suppose the string contains a hex value of 72 (which represents the char 'r' in ACSII) and just before the push_back operation for the output string, the value of p and lut would be:-
p = "789ABCDEF"
lut = "0123456789ABCDEF"

but, (p - lut) in this function is yielding 7 as a result. i don't quite understand how this happens.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pointer arithmetic.

The *value* of `p` is not `"7890ABCDEF"`.  Rather that's the content stored at the address held in `p`.  Since `p` is a pointer, it's *value* is an address.

`lut` points to element 0, `p` points to element 7 in the same array.  Therefore `p - lut` is 7.

For any `n`, `p + n` is the same as `&p[n]`, that is, the address of the `n`-th element.  Here that fact is used in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following, this prints out 'A' (0x41 is A).

```
std::string str="41";
std::stringstream ss; 
ss << std::hex << str;
int i;
ss >> i;
std::cout << static_cast<char>(i);
```

Comment: i didn't ask for an alternative way for doing it. 
i just want to understand how this happens:- 
p = "789ABCDEF" lut = "0123456789ABCDEF"

but, (p - lut) in this function is yielding 7 as a result. i don't quite understand how this happens.??

Answer (score 0):

I ll try to break down what is happening

```
 output.push_back(((p - lut) << 4) | (q - lut));
```

suppose "72"

we do the difference of address, to get the index

```
p - lut = 7 
q - lut = 2
```

apply 4 bit left shift for left part of the hex code

```
7 << 4 == 0x70
```

binary or to merge the two

```
0x70 | 0x02 == 0x72
```